# jquery easyui datagrid Error

Tags: jquery-ui, datagrid

i got error whenever i call this line in my any function...

```
$('#tt').datagrid('getRows').length;
```

FireBug Error:

```
TypeError: $.data(...) is undefined
return $.data(jq[0],"datagrid").data.rows;
```

My Code..
test.aspx

```
<table id="tt" title="DataGrid" tabindex="511" singleselect="true" idfield="Id">
```

And

```
function _insertFilter(){
        var index = $('#tt').datagrid('getRows').length; // error 
        var row = $('#tt').datagrid('getEditors', index); //
        if (row)
            row = [];//error handle by this
        if (row.length>0 && !row[0].target.val() && !row[1].target.val()){

        } else {
            var toAdd = true;
            var editors = $('#tt').datagrid('getEditors',   ($('#tt').datagrid('getRows').length-1));
            if (editors.length>0) {
                if (editors[0].target.val() == "" && editors[1].target.val() == "")
                    toAdd = false;
            }
```

before this i initialize my table  with  below function

```
 function FilterDataGrid() {
        $(function() {
            var lastIndex;                
            $('#tt').datagrid({
                title: '',
                idField: 'Id',
                height: 160,                    
                width: 850, 
                singleSelect:true,
                columns: [[
                    { field: 'Id', title: 'Id', hidden: true, width: 60 },
                    { field: 'AccountName', title: 'Account', width: 390,
                        editor:{
            type:'text',.....more code //bt  here is no problem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are Getting Error Not For This Line:

```
$('#tt').datagrid('getRows').length;
```

You Are Getting Error For This Line:

```
$('#tt').datagrid('getEditors', index)
```

Try This

```
var index=$('#tt').datagrid('getRows').length-1;         
$('#dgItmInfo').datagrid('selectRow', index).datagrid('getEditors', index);
```

//there was a "b" and no a "n" on "index" word (ibdex)