# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datagrid is not a function

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-easyui

I am trying to make use of EasyUI library. I am having issues getting the Data grid working.

I have provided below what I have so far:

**Header**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="user_control_datagrid"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    $( ".user_control_search" ).click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("FORM SEARCH CLICKED");

        var formData = $('#user_control_form').serializeArray();

        console.log("Form Data: ", formData);

        $('#user_control_datagrid').datagrid({
            url:'user.php',
            queryParams:formData,
            columns:[[
                {field:'code',title:'Code',width:100},
                {field:'name',title:'Name',width:100},
                {field:'price',title:'Price',width:100,align:'right'}
            ]]
        });
    });
});
```

Every time I try to run this, I am getting this error :

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datagrid is not a function**

Please can someone advise me what I am doing wrong and how I could fix this issue ?

Thank You

Comment: make sure your js code is inside `$( document ).ready(function() {});`

Comment: I have tried that but still the same error. I have updated my question to show you exactly how i got it as.

Comment: Make sure you are using single jquery version. see here https://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=6542.0

Comment: if you replace your div `#user_control_datagrid` with a table, it looks like datagrid works with table no?

Comment: If `.datagrid()` is not a function - `.datagrid` doesn't exist.. Make sure you load your files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
var index=$('#user_control_datagrid').datagrid('getRows').length-1;         
$('#dgItmInfo').datagrid('selectRow', index).datagrid('getEditors', index);
```

Comment: I can't even run this line because the same error comes back saying datagrid is not function. $('#user_control_datagrid').datagrid('getRows')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979478/jquery-easyui-datagrid-error